# Sampling distribution and estimators?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Consider the following question ([original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tCAO.jpg)):

> Now consider the estimator $$S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n ( X_i - \overline{X} )^2$$ where $\overline{X}$ is the mean of $X_1 , X_2 , \ldots , X_n$. You are *given* the following results.
>
> 1. The sampling distribution of $S^2$ is $\frac{\sigma^2}{n-1} \chi^2_{n-1}$.
> 2. The mean of a $\chi^2_{n-1}$ random variable is $n-1$.
> 3. The variance of a $\chi^2_{n-1}$ random variable is $2(n-1)$.
>
> You are *not* required to prove these results.)
>
> **(iv)** Use these results to show that $S^2$ is an unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$ and that its variance is $\frac{2\sigma^4}{n-1}$.

On question (iv) the only way I can think of doing it is by using the sampling distribution. If I am correct the sampling distribution of an estimator is just its pdf. But the way i did this was as follows:
$$ {\rm E}[S^2]=\frac{\sigma^2}{n-1}{\rm E}[\chi_{n-1}^2] $$ But i am sure this is not valid as I don't think you can use the sampling distribution like this. How is the proper way i would do this question and use the sample distribution to find the mean. (I know how to find the mean from a probability density function.)

Comment: I have attempted to transcribe your image in to MathJax. Please check it over to ensure that I didn't introduce any errors.

Answer (score 0):

The formula you wrote is correct, and that is exactly how you are supposed to solve the problem.

Comment: Is the sampling distribution the pdf of the estimator?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: So why don't we need to use an integral?

Comment: You could certainly integrate for the expected value of a chi-square distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom, but they already told you what it is:  it's ${\rm E}[\chi^2_{n-1}] = n-1$.

Comment: would we not have to integrate S^2f(x) where f(x) is the sampling distribution and S^2 the formula given at the top of the page?? What rule lets us do what I have done? (thanks for your help)

Comment: No.  To help you understand, suppose I have two IID standard normal random variables $X_1, X_2$.  Then if I tell you that $Y = X_1^2 + X_2^2$ is $\chi^2_2$, then ${\rm E}[Y] = {\rm E}[\chi^2_2]$.  In other words, the sampling distribution **is** the distribution of $S^2$, which in turn is the distribution of $\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2$ when $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are IID normal random variables.

Comment: To calculate ${\rm E}[Y]$, you would **NOT** write something like $$\int (x_1^2 + x_2^2) f_Y(y) \, dy$$ because that makes no sense.  You *could* write $$\iint (x_1^2 + x_2^2) f_{X_1, X_2}(x_1, x_2) \, dx_1 \, dx_2$$ where $f_{X_1, X_2}$ is the joint distribution, but this is unnecessary because we were told that the distribution of the sum of squares is $\chi^2_2$.

Comment: So i understand that if Y=aX E[Y]=aE[X] this is like the equation at the top of the page. But as i can see it now what we are doing now is if f(y)=aX is the pdf of Y then E[Y]=aE[X] is this correct? and can you expalin why this works?

Comment: When I say "the PDF is the distribution" or "the distribution is the PDF" I don't literally mean $Y = f_Y(y)$.  I'm saying that the distribution of $Y$ is characterized by $f_Y(y)$.  To say $f(y) = aX$ is incorrect.

Comment: Sorry i didn't mean it like that i mean if the PDF of Y is a function of X (not the same as Y=aX) then E[Y]=cE[X] where c is the thing X is multiplied by in the PDF. in this case X= chi-squared and c=σ^2/(n-1)

Comment: I think i understand if R is the sampling distribution of a random variable X then E[R]=E[X] where in the case for estimators their pdf is their sampling distribution?

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\mathbb{E}(S^2)=\frac{\sigma^2}{n-1}\mathbb{E}(X)=\frac{\sigma^2}{n-1}(n-1)=\sigma^2 \,\,$$
for $X \sim \chi_{n-1}^2 \,$ and where the second equality came from the given result ($2$), so that $S^2$ is unbiased for $\sigma^2$. In regards to computing variance, we have
$$\begin{align}\text{Var}(S^2) &= \left(\frac{\sigma^2}{n-1}\right)^2\text{Var}(X) \\&= \left(\frac{\sigma^2}{n-1}\right)^2 2(n-1) \\&= \frac{2\sigma^4}{n-1} \,\,,\end{align}$$
again for $X \sim \chi_{n-1}^2$ and where the second equality here came from the given result ($3$).